# Python 3.4 - How to transform a Pandas Data Panel (not frame) to a mySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, pandas, panel, python-3.4

I am trying to organize some financial data in a 'multidimensional' SQL database so that I can, at a later stage, take slices as needed across time or asset (or attribute such as 'close_price').

Pandas Panel.to_sql seemed like a nice way to do this (albeit a lack of detailed documentation on data panels specifically), and so I have managed to store all the data in a pandas data panel:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Panel.to_sql.html

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 1322 (items) x 2717 (major_axis) x 15 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 1321
Major_axis axis: 2004-01-02 00:00:00 to 2014-12-24 00:00:00
Minor_axis axis: Open to name
```

In this case the Items are Security IDs (or stock symbols), Major_axis are the dates, and Minor_axis hold the various attributes (prices etc.)

I tried (assume 'dp' is the name of this data panel and 'path' is the target path for the database):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///'+ path)
dp.to_sql(name = 'Equities_Data', con = engine, flavor = 'sqlite')
```

This flagged an error that the dtypes were not recognized - and I noticed that .to_sql takes an additional argument dtypes, a dictionary which maps pythonic types to sqlalchemy types. Fine so did this:

```
attributes = list(dp.minor_axis)
values = [sqlalchemy.types.String etc.. ] (populated this with loop)
dtype = dict(zip(attributes, values))
```

This still did not solve the problem for transforming the full datapanel but did manage to allow me to transform a dataframe slice to a .db file.

i.e.: dp[0].to_sql(name = 'Equities_Data', con = engine, flavor = 'sqlite',     dtype = dtype, index = dp.major_axis)

So I guess my question is: has anyone managed to get this sort of thing to work in the past? Is this even possible? Easier ways? I am all ears.

Otherwise, if I loop create all 2D slices of my panel as databases is there a way to combine these in SQL to form a 3D-like object where I can slice through as I want?

Thanks so much in advance.

** EDIT **

Taking a deeper look into the pandas.io.sql files it seems that Panel.to_sql method actually is only limited to dataframes. A little bit misleading.

Question then is: Is there an easier way to achieve aggregating all this data in a 3D like object in SQL?

Thank you

Comment: How do you want to represent a Panel in a sqlite table? But indeed, the docs on Panel.to_sql are misleading. However, normally you should get a NotImplementedError instead of some error about the dtypes.

Comment: Can you show the initial error you got when trying `to_sql` on a panel. If this is not NotImplementedError, this looks like a bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking a look Joris, the error is indeed 'NotImplementedError' : 


  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 977, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 977, in to_sql
    dtype=dtype)

File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 534, in to_sql
    raise NotImplementedError

Answer (score 2):

Weird.. but I think I might have found a way to achieve something relatively close to the goal completely by accident. Will share in case this is helpful to anyone else out there!

Start by defining a single engine / connection for sqlite:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///'+ path + 'Equities_Data.db')
```

Then loop for each dataframe in the datapanel and create mini datatables (in the big Equities_Data.db , i.e. many datatables in database):

```
for j in range(len(list(dp.items))):

    dp[j].to_sql(name = dp[j].symbol[0], con = engine, flavor = 'sqlite', dtype = dtype)
```

In this case each small database is named by the stock's symbol.

The end result is a database which has several datatables inside it. It is not exactly a perfect 3D structure as you can only access items in one direction - but believe that attributes can then be linked across datatables together so that you can slice in other ways (SQL newbie here).